# ta.max function is not giving historical max for variable

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So, I'm trying to normalize the accumulation distribution indicator to generate a new indicator called "normalized ad". To do this, I used `ta.min (ad)` and `ta.max(ad)` which from what I believe is not giving the desired output of the minimum and maximum value, respectively, for the accumulation/distribution indicator.

I exported the data to Excel, calculated the min and max values from that, replaced that with the functions `ta.max(ad)` and `ta.min(ad)` and then I do get the desired output.

Could you help with why the max  or min values aren't being calculated correctly. Or how could I normalize the data set taking into account the entire historical dataset of Accumulation/Distribution.

The code is as follows:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Accumulation/Distribution", shorttitle="Accum/Dist")

ad = ta.cum(close==high and close==low or high==low ? 0 : ((2*close-low-high)/(high-low))*volume) 
normalizedad = 100*(ad - ta.min(ad)) / (ta.max(ad) - ta.min(ad))
plot(normalizedad,color=color.green)
```

[Expected Output (Obtained with Excel with Formula shown)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5UhS.jpg)

[Pine script Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mh68.jpg)

Comment: Please show us how you are not geting the historical values. What do you expect and what do you get? Please give us a minimal example.

Comment: @vitruvius Because Pine does not return values, I have added the output images from Excel and Pine. Output obtained from Pine shows a rather erratic behaviour at first.

Answer (score 0):

You will get different results because your datasets are different.
**Pine script:**
As the execution model runs your script on historical data, pine script calculates for you on each bar what the min/max values are until that exact bar time. No future values are known at that point. That's how the execution model works.
**Excel:**
You have your complete historical dataset at hand at once that you use in your formula for the calculation.
So what excel gives you pine script could only do at the very last bar - based on data availability.

Comment: is there any workaround this to back test a strategy that uses normalized data sets

Comment: You have the complete data availability only at the last bar. So if you can do your operations there. Calculations could be possible there - but you could face performance issues - but plotting would not be.